# Topology of fiber bundles over $S^{1}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I am interested in the topology of locally trivial fiber bundles over $S^{1}$ but have not been able to find a resource covering this case at a level I, as a non expert in topological matters, am able to understand.

In particular, given a locally trivial fiber bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow S^{1}$ it seems reasonable to me that the topology of the total space $E$ should be fully specified by the gluing of the space on the boundary. I.e. the total space can be given as $[0,1] \times F$ where $(0,f)$ and $(1, \phi(f))$ are identified. Here $F = \pi^{-1}(x \in E)$ is the standard fiber and $\phi: F \rightarrow F$ is a self-homoemorphism. The topology of the total space should then only depend on the conjugacy class of $\phi$ in the mapping class group of $F$.

My question is the following

1. Is the above correct in general, and if so is there some reference that covers this simple case I can have a look at?
2. In the above I made reference to the topology of the total space. Up to what level (homeomorphism/homotopy etc) does the mapping class group element $\phi$ belongs to specify the global topology?

Comment: What do you mean by the mapping class group? The canonical definition is only for surfaces without boundary. Also, do you know that a fiber bundle over an interval is trivial?

Comment: I know that fiber bundles over an interval are trivial, the considered case here is the smallest possible deviation from this I suppose. I am fine with having $F$ be a closed manifold which should be enough to define the mapping class group as I gather from your comment.

Comment: If $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are homeomorphisms which are conjugate in the sense you describe, it looks like you should be able to construct a bundle isomorphism between their bundles (which is in general stronger than a homeomorphism between the total spaces).

Comment: No, for higher dimensional manifolds there are many inequivalent definitions of the MCG. It is your responsibility to state what you mean.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this thanks for pointing it out @Moishe Kohan. After having a quick look it seems reasonable to me to take the mapping class group in the sense of the homotopy category, as discussed on the wikipedia page. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group) However, more generally my question is about whether there is any precise formulation of my statement such that it is correct, I assume if the statement makes little sense it should be false for any definition of the mapping class group one choses.